# How to get dirname from path

Tags: bash, find, dirname

I have this:

```
find . -type f -name '*_test.go' | xargs dirname
```

but I get:

> usage: dirname path

the output of

```
$ find . -type f -name '*_test.go'
```

is:

```
./pkg_test.go
./v3/organization/organization_test.go
./v3/common/pkg_test.go
./v3/model/boil_main_test.go
./v3/model/boil_queries_test.go
./v3/model/advances_test.go
./v3/model/boil_suites_test.go
./v3/model/psql_main_test.go
./v3/model/psql_suites_test.go
```

anyone know how I can get the dirname of the file? Maybe I need absolute paths?

Comment: standard / non-GNU `dirname` only takes a single argument. `find . -type f -name '*_test.go' -exec dirname {} \;`

Comment: or, if you're _really_ using bash as your tags say, you can get rid of both `find` and `dirname`: `shopt -s globstar nullglob; gos=(./**/*.go); printf "%s\n" "${gos[@]%/*.go}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three ways:

First, your `xargs` way fails because you give `dirname` more than one pathname at a time.  Instead, pass pathnames one by one to it:

```
find . -type f -name '*_test.go' -print0 | xargs -0 -r -I {} dirname {}
```

The `-print0` with `find` and `-0` with `xargs` passes the pathnames as a nul-delimited list instead of as a newline-delimited list. The `-r` option for `xargs` will make sure that `dirname` isn't run if there is no input from `find`.

If you know that your filenames do not contain embedded newlines:

```
find . -type f -name '*_test.go' | xargs -r -I {} dirname {}
```

Secondly, call a in-line shell script with `find` that runs `dirname` on the files one by one:

```
find . -type f -name '*_test.go' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        dirname "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

Alternatively, don't call `dirname` but use a parameter substitution in the loop (quicker):

```
find . -type f -name '*_test.go' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        printf "%s\n" "${pathname%/*}"
    done' sh {} +
```

Thirdly, if you're using GNU `find`, use its `-printf`:

```
find . -type f -name '*_test.go' -printf '%h\n'
```

---

Lastly, if you are using `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- ./**/*_test.go(.ND:h)
```

The `(.ND:h)` glob modifier asks the previous globbing pattern to only expand to regular files (`.`), and to expand to nothing if there is no files matching the pattern (`N`, like `nullglob` in `bash`), and to also include hidden names (`D`, like `dotglob` in `bash`).  The `:h` at the end causes the "head" of each matching pathname to be returned (i.e. the directory part of the pathname without the filename).

You could do something equivalent in `bash` with a loop like so:

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob

for pathname in ./**/*_test.go; do
    if [[ -f $pathname ]] && [[ ! -h $pathname ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "${pathname%/*}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Is `-r` necessary? My local tests suggest no: if `find` results in no matches, `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} dirname {}` simply does not print to stdout and then exits with code 0.